# can i call an https url in localhost wamp server using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class controller extends CI_Controller {    
public function
    __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->library('curl'); 
            $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
              }

        public function callingurl()

        {
            $get_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';  
            echo $this->curl->simple_get($get_url, false, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => true)); 


        }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the HTTPS Protocol which access the SSL certificate.
So make your code as...

```
    public function callingurl()
    {
        $get_url = 'https://www.google.com'; 

        $this->curl->ssl(FALSE); // making the ssl certificate to false;

        echo $this->curl->simple_get($get_url, false, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => true)); 


    }
```

Comment: thank you..but i want to know how to pass an API through $get_url for sending a message.. actually i'm new to this so could u please help me...

Comment: and  i am also looking for the way to send a message to a mobile number when i submit (means it a registration of) a form in database...can anyone please guide me fix my problem

Comment: give a try like this...
 
 
 `$url = 'http://smsgateway.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=username&pwd=123456789&to=0123456789&sid=abcd&msg=hiiiii';
 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        
        return false;
    }`

Comment: .where should i want to  insert this code...sorry to say i didn't understand the programming part..

Comment: make it as a function and use it... if the curl is success it will return true else it will return false...

Comment: ya nothing will be displayed.... check the mobile to which you send the message..

Comment: for that i want  to change $url as http://smsgateway.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=username&pwd=123456789&to=(a valid mobile number)&sid=abcd&msg=hiiiii'; ..right...

Comment: ya.. you need to change that to your gateway url ....access using the username and password which you got from the gateway which you singed in...

Comment: and i tried in other  $url=http://promo.blastsms.in/sendsms.jps?user=xxxx&password=xxxx&mobiles=0123456789sms=test&senderid=xxxx&version=3'; with actuall username ,password, sender id .still no respones wat should i want to do next.

Comment: there seems to be no documentation on how to use the api... better contact support of that smsgateway....

Comment: can u please tell me how can use string concatenation inside an url.......like i just want to put my $url = 'http://promo.blastsms.in/sendsms.jsp?user=xxx&password=xxxx&mobiles=xxxx&sms=test&senderid=xxxx&version=3'; as $user=xxxxx;   $pass=xxxxx;   $mobile=XXXXX; $senderid=xxxx; and then call

Answer (score 0):

```
$baseurl = "http://promo.blastsms.in/sendsms.jsp?";

$user = "xxxxx";

$password = "xxxxx";

$api_id = "xxxxx";

$url="$baseurl/&user=$user&password=$password&mobiles=$to&sms=$text&senderid=$api_id&version=$version";
```

this way I split my url.